# Show y is odd in the equation $y^3 =x^2 +2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Found a question which asks you to find all integer solutions $y^3 =x^2 +2$ .    In order to do so, it first asks you to show that y is odd.  How would one go about showing this?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Suppose $\,y\,$ is even, then also $\,x\,$ must be even, but then $\;x^2+2 \equiv 2\pmod 4\;$ , and since $\,y^3 \not \equiv 2 \pmod 4\;\;\forall\,y\in\Bbb Z\;$ we're done.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose not. Then $x^2=y^3-2$, hence $x$, is even. Therefore, $2=y^3-x^2$ is divisible by $2^2$, which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 3):

If $y=2k$ then $\color{brown}{x^2=}8k^3+2=\color{brown}{2(4k^3+1)}$.
 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is even, $y^3\equiv0\pmod 8\equiv0\pmod 4$

So, $x^2=y^3-2\equiv-2\pmod 4\equiv2$

Now, $0^2\equiv0\pmod 4,(\pm1)^2\equiv1, (\pm2)^2\equiv0$